# Tensorboard: Filter out certain time steps

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is there a way to filter out the first X  timesteps when visualizing the histograms and scalars, only showing steps > X?

Much like the zooming feature for scalars, but something which updates as time progresses, and something which works for histograms too?